# Deduction guide for brace initializer list

Tags: c++, c++20, initializer-list, list-initialization, deduction-guide

There is a implementation quite similar to `std::initializer_list` used in an environment where standart C++ library is not available:

```
template<typename T>
class initializer_list {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = const T &;
    using const_reference = const T &;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using iterator = const T *;
    using const_iterator = const T *;

private:
    iterator m_array;
    size_type m_length;

    constexpr initializer_list( const_iterator array, size_type length ) noexcept : m_array( array ), m_length( length ) {}

public:
    constexpr initializer_list( void ) noexcept : m_array( nullptr ), m_length( 0 ) {}

    /* Number of elements */
    constexpr size_type size( void ) const noexcept {
        return m_length;
    }

    /* First element */
    constexpr const_iterator begin( void ) const noexcept {
        return m_array;
    }

    /* One past the last element */
    constexpr const_iterator end( void ) const noexcept {
        return begin() + size();
    }
};

template<typename T>
constexpr const T * begin( initializer_list<T> list ) noexcept {
    return list.begin();
}

template<typename T>
constexpr const T * end( initializer_list<T> list ) noexcept {
    return list.end();
}
```

Then such `initializer_list<T>` is about to be used in another class constructor:

```
template<typename T>
struct user {
    user( initializer_list<T> init_values ) { ... }
};
```

and the intension to use both things together:

```
user<int> sample { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Obviously, the compiler does not know how to deduce the type of the brace initializer list so that it uses initializer_list as implemented above. I suppose some kind of deduction guide shall be implemented to connect my implementation of initializer_list and the brace initializer list. But I have no clue how to implement such.

**Can someone advise me how to implement the described deduction guide?**

Comment: Even if it did know you wanted to use that class, the compiler wouldn't know how.  `std::intiializer_list` is magic.

Comment: The deduction guide can be written for `user`, but I don't see a constructor for your `initializer_list` that can handle a brace initializer.

Comment: User code can't replace how built-in language features work. You'd need to hook your implementation into your compiler. But if it *has the option* it will also have the (very light) header available.

Comment: @cigien: my implementation more or less copies std::initializer_list and there is nothing which takes brace initializer...

Comment: If you want any chance of the compiler recognizing this, it needs to be in `<initializer_list>` and in `std`, but at that point your header might as well be the (freestanding) one that the compiler ships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in an environment where standart C++ library is not available

There is no such thing. While freestanding C++ implementations are free to only implement parts of the standard library, there are some components which *all* valid C++ implementations must provide. `std::initializer_list` is among these components.

As such, if you have a valid C++11 or higher implementation of C++, then you must have the `<initializer_list>` header and its contents. This is not optional. If your implementation doesn't provide one, then it is defective.

The reason it is not optional is that the important functionality of `std::initializer_list` (that is, its generation from a braced-init-list) is a function of the C++ *language*, not of the library. That is, it is *impossible* for code outside of the compiler to make the `{}` grammatical construct become a type that is exactly analogous to how `std::initializer_list` behaves.

Consider your code:

```
user<int> sample { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

If you think about it, this ought to mean that a constructor of `user<int>` will be called that takes 5 parameters. That's what it would mean if `user` had a constructor of 5 integer parameters, after all. But that's not what you want it to mean, and it wouldn't mean that for `vector<int>`. Why?

Because C++'s language has a special rule about list initialization that detects the presence of a constructor which takes a `std::initializer_list` that matches the braced-init-list types, and then creates a `std::initializer_list` to pass to this constructor. This rule keys off of the presences of a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list` and *no other type*.

Your code does not work, not because of a lack of deduction guides, but because your `initializer_list` type has no special rules as far as the language is concerned.

You cannot recreate this language behavior with a user-defined type. Just as you cannot make `typeid` return a type other than `std::type_info`. Just as you cannot make `enum class byte: unsigned char{};` have the same behavior as `std::byte`.